# Creating a sidebar with buttons

Tags: css, html, button, nav

I'm trying to create a sidebar with large clickable areas that use hyperlinks and have a hover effect. Do I accomplish this by inserting button types within my list? or is there a simpler way? This is what I have so far (pay no attention to the ugly colors);

[image]

Html:

```
<div id="sideNav">
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"><a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Account<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Live Events <a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Football<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Baseball<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Soccer<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Basketball<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Hockey<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> MMA<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> eSports<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Tennis<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Cricket<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Golf<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Badminton<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Handball<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Rugby<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Snooker<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Table Tennis<a></li><hr>
        <li<a class="menu" href="#"> Volleyball<a></li><hr>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu a {
    line-height:50px; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px dotted black;
    display:block;
}

a:hover{
    background-color:#fff;}
```

Comment: I want to be able to click anywhere on the boxes within the sidebar and have it link me to another part of the site. But I can't even get the links to work, I've tried inserting them in the lists but it doesn't respond to my clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you correctly.

You want to create a sidebar that has hover effects right?

Use the pseudo-class :hover. This would be your CSS code:

```
a.menu:link {
line-height:50px; 
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
color:#fff;
border:1px dotted black;
display:block;
}
a.menu:visited {
color:$fff;
}
a.menu:hover {
color:#393939;
}
```

In the :hover class, just write the properties you want to change. In this case, the button's color will change from #fff to #393939 when you hover on it.

If you want, you can also add transition effects. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp
Note that transition effects have limited browser compatibility.

---

Also, to point out some errors in your code:
Your *li* opening tag is incomplete.
Your *a* tag is not closed correctly.
This is what you had:

```
<li<a class="menu" href="#"> Account<a></li>
```

This is what it should be:

```
<li><a class="menu" href="#"> Account</a></li>
```

In addition to that, *li* tags are usually enclosed by *ul* tags. I don't think they work on their own.

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Lastly, the *hr* tag is not necessary. You already have borders on the bottom of each button, and the *li* tag will break the lines for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I was also having trouble with inserting hyperlinks within the list. it doesn't work, I click and nothing happens. I want to be able to click anywhere on the box.

Comment: @Calisto You're welcome. Did you use the exact same code in your page? For one, I noticed that your _<li>_ opening tag is incomplete. You're missing the ">" part. That could cause problems with the rest of your code. I always use the _width_ and _height_ property instead of _line-height_ for menu buttons, and that has always worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
#sideNav
{
  width:100px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  border-right:12px solid blue;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/dh1ayk34/)